# Title, composer, source of a duet that starts "Cantami cuando el mar é color tortura"

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

(My apologies for any mistakes in transcription of the initial lyrics!)

We saw [Anna Netrebko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anna_Netrebko) and [Yusif Eyvazov](https://yusifeyvazov.com/) last night, and this was their last encore (therefore, not listed in the program).  I'd never heard it before, but I enjoyed it enough to try to identify it -  but all I can find are two videos of Netrebko and Eyvazoz singing it, with "Cantami" as the only identification.  (Since these aren't official videos, I'm guessing that the people who posted them didn't know either.)

Can anybody tell me the actual title of the song (I will be a little embarrassed if it actually turns out to be just "Cantami"), the composer, and - if it's from an opera - which one?

Ripped from Russian TV:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dX_q4xRxahk

Comment: Since this question was revived yesterday,, I went back and watched the Russian TV clip I originally posted.  A few bars into the performance, there's a chyron identifying the song, and it does say "Cantami" if you look very closely - but the video quality is so bad that I couldn't have read it if I hadn't already known what it said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Song by Igor Krutoy: Cantami

https://www.facebook.com/operafashionvictims/videos/989218641192852/

At the bottom of the page is the music name
http://www.koelner-philharmonie.de/veranstaltung/118270/

Comment: Well, I will be dipped.  I did have a sneaking suspicion that it was newer than the rest of the program... but not _that_ new!  Also, I actually have a couple of Igor Krutoy's CDs, and this feels like a bit of a departure for him.  Thanks for turning it up!  One lives and learns.

Comment: Aaaaaand now that I know it's Krutoy, there are clues littered all over the web.  Ain't it always the way?

Comment: I did not find any other clues. Maybe you need to search with another alphabet : )

Comment: I did - and what I turned up was an article (on an opera-fan blog) that mentioned that Netrebko is a fan of Krutoy's music, and that Netrebko and Eyvazov's first CD together will be recordings of Krutoy's songs.  (The article was from 2015, and although it spoke in future tense I can't quite tell whether this CD actually exists yet, as of 2017.)  She says that, although she never intended to record "crossover" music, Krutoy's music is simply too beautiful not to record.  Now, I like him OK, but that seemed a little over-the-top to me... ah, well.